# Understanding convolution and subtle processing to alter timbres of sounds

Tags: timbre, modification

When you use convolution reverb to alter the timbre of a sound, does anybody  have some ideas about how this works?

For example, you load an IR of a metal ride cymbal and you send voices through it, the timbre has a metallic ring.

What would be usable for creating a fluffy, soft, pillow timbre?

Are there any other sly manipulations that this forum would care to share?

Answer (score 1):

There have been some great discussions on this subject, [here's a quick link](https://sound.stackexchange.com/search?q=convolution).

As I understand it, convolution algorithms work on the principle of common frequencies being reinforced. Example, if you have a source sound with a lot of midrange frequencies and you process it through an impulse response which also has a lot of midrange, the resulting sound will be…wait for it…heavy on the midrange! Knowing that, you can push voices through metallic IRs, glassy/crystal IRs, or doors through IRs that are chock full of low end, like tunnels, cisterns or other large spaces.

If you're looking for a soft-type of timbre, I'd try some of the smaller spaces like closets or boxes. Also remember that you can craft your own IRs using simple sounds like a finger snap run through a multi-tap delay, or a gunshot echoing through a canyon.

Comment: Good point.  It really does reinforce frequencies.

Comment: @Jay, I ended up using ice cubes clinking in a glass and then sleighbells for a IR response for a memory verb soak using IRL, IRL's convolution "self'noise" or convolution coloring is a timbre in itself

Comment: http://www.soundonsound.com/sos/sep10/articles/convolution.htm